# Making sprite appear at random position

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a sprite "comet" appear at a random position at random times. So far, I wanted to test if my random position code works, however, I can't seem to even see the sprite. This is my code:

```
 func spawnAtRandomPosition() {
        let height = self.view!.frame.height
        let width = self.view!.frame.width

        let randomPosition = CGPointMake(CGFloat(arc4random()) % height, CGFloat(arc4random()) % width)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "comet")
        sprite.position = randomPosition
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
```

As I said, I'm not seeing **anything**. Any help? If you already know how to make it appear at a random time that would be appreciated as well, because that's having problems of its own, however this is my focus right now. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if that is the issue, but the x position should depend on the width, and the y position on the height. You have it the wrong way around.

Comment: I fixed that, but it didn't resolve the problem

Comment: This should'nt even compile in Swift 3. 1) use the `truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:)` method of `CGFloat` rather than the (non-existing) `%` operator for `lhs` and `rhs` being of type `CGFloat`, and 2) use `CGPoint(x:y:)` initializer. E.g. `let randomPosition = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: width), y: CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: height))`.

Comment: @Guac Note the difference between scene and a view. They don't have necessarily the same size. So your objects can end up off screen. The scene is by default 1024x768. Which is very different from a size of a view of iPhones.

Comment: @Whirlwind Thats what I figured was the problem too. My answer fixes this and some other issues with the code

Comment: @Nik I saw that. I just mentioned the fact about different sizes because you haven't. You did it in a right way without explanation. Anyways, you have my upvote ;)

Comment: @Nik I don't think editing is needed. Your code should do the thing. And there is a comment already here so...

Answer (score 1):

Your code for setting the random position is incorrect. Additionally, your code has issues that should make it impossible to compile in Swift 3. Your full function should look like this:

```
func spawnAtRandomPosition() {
        let height = UInt32(self.size.height)
        let width = UInt32(self.size.width)

        let randomPosition = CGPoint(x: Int(arc4random_uniform(width)), y: Int(arc4random_uniform(height)))

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "comet")
        sprite.position = randomPosition
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
```

Note the changes to `randomPosition` and the height and width:

```
let randomPosition = CGPoint(x: Int(arc4random_uniform(width)), y: Int(arc4random_uniform(height)))
```

This determines a random value between 0 and your width and does the same thing for the height.

As for the height and width, see @Whirlwind's comment on the question explaining the difference between the view and the scene.

Additionally, you may want to check if you're setting up your node properly (set size, try with fixed location, etc) before you test the random positioning, to determine where the problem truly lies.

Comment: The `randomPosition` line pulls up an error "Cannot convert a value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'UInt32'". Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: no, the error changed, although it means basically the same thing. It says "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGPoint' with an argument list of type '(x: UInt32, y: UInt32)'."

Comment: No, should I? I don't understand how that would change anything.

Comment: it was a good idea, but not the problem. I also added a zPosition specification yet nothing

Comment: I made the position a cgpoint in the center of the screen and I could see it. I'm just gonna search online to see if I can find something. I think it might just be outside the bounds of the view

Comment: @Guac I think I figured it out. Updated answer. Getting height and width was incorrect, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this bit of code and it works for me:

```
    let randomNum = CGPoint(x:Int (arc4random() % 1000), y: 1)

    let actionMove =  SKAction.moveTo(randomNum, duration: 1)
```

I only wanted the x to be randomized, however if you need "y" to be randomized as well, you can just copy the specification to x to y.

Comment: This just determines a random number between 0 and 999. Your scene's width isn't going to be 999. Right now, if `randomNum` was 999 and your scene's width was 768 (default width for portrait), you still might not see the node (it could be off the scene)